# NHibernate.XmlSerializers - Não existe?

Tags: c#, .net

> Não foi possível carregar arquivo ou assembly
>   'NHibernate.XmlSerializers, Version=4.0.0.4000, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4' ou uma de suas dependências. O
>   sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado.

Minha aplicação começou a solicitar uma DLL que não existe, antes era `minhaapp.dll.XmlSerializers` então adicionei esse código ao projeto e o erro mudou de "endereço" e foi para a DLL do NHibernate

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild" DependsOnTargets="AssignTargetPaths;Compile;ResolveKeySource" Inputs="$(MSBuildAllProjects);@(IntermediateAssembly)" Outputs="$(OutputPath)$(_SGenDllName)">
    <!-- Delete the file because I can't figure out how to force the SGen task. -->
    <Delete
      Files="$(TargetDir)$(TargetName).XmlSerializers.dll"
      ContinueOnError="true" />
    <SGen
      BuildAssemblyName="$(TargetFileName)"
      BuildAssemblyPath="$(OutputPath)"
      References="@(ReferencePath)"
      ShouldGenerateSerializer="true"
      UseProxyTypes="false"
      KeyContainer="$(KeyContainerName)"
      KeyFile="$(KeyOriginatorFile)"
      DelaySign="$(DelaySign)"
      ToolPath="$(TargetFrameworkSDKToolsDirectory)"
      Platform="$(Platform)">
      <Output
       TaskParameter="SerializationAssembly"
       ItemName="SerializationAssembly" />
    </SGen>
  </Target>
```

Alguém tem alguma sugestão?

Comment: O erro só acontece em Debug?

Comment: Não, acontece em release também. Se implementar `static void CurrentDomain_FirstChanceException(object sender, System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.FirstChanceExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            FileLog.GravarLog(e.Exception, "CurrentDomain_FirstChanceException");
        }` é possível capturar o erro.

Comment: Segundo o Ayende, este erro deve ser desconsiderado: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nhusers/d07afiAPRRM